# Snort version and ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, snort

I have ubuntu 22.04 desktop
What's the snort version that works perfectly in ubuntu 22.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the version that's in the [official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/snort) - version `2.9.15.1-6build1`.

Remember to enable the `universe` repository - you can do this by uncommenting the following lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe
 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe
 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
```

Comment: i installed this version by this cmd "sudo apt-get install snort -y" what's the difference between this installation and the installation step by step for example of snort 3 in this document"https://kifarunix.com/install-and-configure-snort-3-on-ubuntu/" i mean why with this version"2.9.15.1-6build1" just i did this cmd "sudo apt-get install snort -y" and with snort 3 i dis many cmd and steps to be installed

Comment: Without digging any deeper, that guide is about building and compiling snort 3 manually. This is for advanced users, to get a version that is newer than the pre-built packages (which largely follows the Debian packages).